# Waiting for .exe output in Azure Function Apps

Tags: c#, api, asynchronous, azure-functions, synchronous

**I am trying to receive the output from an .exe application in an Azure Function App. The Function app is triggered by a HTTP request.**

The function app triggers and runs the executable. I then want to wait for the .exe to run and return the output as a Json string in the HTTP response if possible. Here is my code:

```
namespace FunctionApp
{
    public static class NmapFunction
    {
        [FunctionName("NmapFunction")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(

            // wait for HTTP trigger on et or post method. Route is defualt.
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string output = string.Empty;

            //Start the nmap .exe
            var Process = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "Nmap.exe",
                    Arguments = "-sS -Pn 127.0.0.1",
                    UseShellExecute = true,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                }
            };

            Process.Start();

            while (!Process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = Process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();

                //add each line to the output string
                output += line;
            }

            Process.WaitForExit();

            string toolOutput = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new ToolRunResult { Result = output }).ToString();

            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(ToolOutput, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
            };

        }
```

I am receiving a 500 internal server error when I run the HTTP request. This is because of an `System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Diagnostics.Process.dll` error in the `while` loop. I believe this is because this is a synchromous action and as i understand Azure function apps must be asynchronous.

So, my question is **What is the best way to get the output from this .exe process? Is it even possible?**

The `ToolRunResult` class:

```
internal class ToolRunResult
{
    internal int StatusCode { get; set; }
    internal string Result { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I reckon you'd need to spin up a VM to do what you're wanting to do.  I can't imagine that launching an executable on a serverless environment would be permissable by Microsoft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **What is the best way to get the output from this .exe process? Is it even possible?**

Yes, It is possible in Azure Function.

#### Please follow the Workaround to run the nMap.exe in Azure Function

Here I am using a Timer trigger to run the **.exe** file and capturing the Output response of the **.exe**.

```cs
public void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */3 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            var p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            string eOut = null;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            p.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
            { eOut += e.Data; });
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Nmap\\nmap.exe";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-sS -Pn 127.0.0.1";
            p.Start();

            // To avoid deadlocks, use an asynchronous read operation on at least one of the streams.  
            p.BeginErrorReadLine();
            string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            p.WaitForExit();

            log.LogInformation($"The nMap Exe Result are:\n'{output}'");
            log.LogInformation($"\nError stream: {eOut}");
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
        }
```

#### Result

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes this worked. Also found another solution. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

Error was in the `StartInfo` Variable. `UseShellExecute` must be set to `false`.

Unsure of the reasoning behind this, but it did the trick.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).