# Azure Functions and queues

Tags: laravel, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-storage-queues

I want to create an app that supports multiple users. Every user can upload multiple files and each file uploaded needs to be processed by a pipeline (for example processing1.exe -> processing2.py -> processing3.exe). The results must be made available to the user after processing.
The backend is in Laravel.

I have the following questions:

1. I tried running the processing1.exe binary on Azure Functions but I got "access denied". I guess this is because the default Windows image does not have the necessary dependencies installed (Windows SDK). From what I read there are other offerings of "serverless" in Azure like Logic Apps, Custom containers etc. Is there a way to use "serverless"/Azure Functions with that binary? What are my options?
2. Everytime a new file upload is detected (by Laravel), how should I trigger Azure to start processing it? Should I Azure Storage Queues, Azure Service Bus, Event Hub or Event Grid (or something else)?
   Ideally the system shouldn't process all the files from users in a FIFO manner but instead use round-robin (that way if user1 uploads 1000 files and user2 uploads 3 files, user2 wouldn't have to wait for all of user1 files to finish).

Answer (score 0):

**Few of the workarounds for running the .exe file on Azure Functions:**

**Workaround 1**:
There is one of my practical workarounds on running and getting .exe output in Azure Functions, please refer this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71452740/waiting-for-exe-output-in-azure-function-apps/71511570#71511570).

[image]
[image]

**Workaround 2**:

My `.exe file` contains SQL database query that *`insert record into database`* using Azure Function App:

```cs
cmd.CommandText = "insert into [dbo].[debug]([Name]) values('test')";
```

**run.csx**:

```cs
using System;

public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\home\site\wwwroot\TimerTriggerclass1\demofunction.exe";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process.Start();
    string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    string err = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
    process.WaitForExit();

    log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
}
```

Before running the Function App in Azure, we need to upload the .exe file in the Azure Functions App > Functions (TimerTriggerclass1) > Upload File option.
[image]

**Workaround 3**:

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
{

    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    string WorkingDirectoryInfo =@"D:\home\site\wwwroot\TimerTriggerClass1";
    string ExeLocation = @"D:\home\site\wwwroot\TimerTriggerClass1\MyApplication.exe";
    Process proc = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();

    try
    {
    info.WorkingDirectory = WorkingDirectoryInfo;
    info.FileName = ExeLocation;
    info.Arguments = "";
    info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
    info.UseShellExecute = false;
    info.CreateNoWindow = true;
    proc.StartInfo = info;
    proc.Refresh();
    proc.Start();
    proc.WaitForInputIdle();
    proc.WaitForExit();
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
}
```

> Everytime a new file upload is detected (by Laravel), how should I trigger Azure to start processing it? Should I Azure Storage Queues, Azure Service Bus, Event Hub or Event Grid (or something else)? Ideally the system shouldn't process all the files from users in a FIFO manner but instead use round-robin (that way if user1 uploads 1000 files and user2 uploads 3 files, user2 wouldn't have to wait for all of user1 files to finish).

For this process, the pure ***serverless*** approach like **Azure Functions** with Blob Storage Trigger or **Azure Logic Apps** with Blob Storage Trigger is better.

Whenever the new file is uploaded, then the **Blob Storage** will trigger the **Azure Function** to process the files immediately.
It will not make wait of the user 2 until the user1 finishes all files processing. User 2 can get the processed result at the same time when files are uploaded.

In Comparison, **Logic Apps** also does the same functionality whenever the files are added or modified but Logic Apps has built-in processing methods and connectors like after processing, share or save it to some other storages or mails whereas if you need customized functionality before/on/after processing the files uploaded on Azure Storage, **Azure functions** is the best approach to write the custom optimized code.

Comment: I had tried Workaround 2 and it didn't work. I tried in Kudu as well and got the same thing (access denied). I will try the others methods as well, thanks. I read somewhere that blob storage trigger is not as reliable as queue storage trigger, is that true? Also how can I make sure that user1 will only get user1 results and not user2's results? Wouldn't the default blob storage trigger be insufficient for this case?

Comment: User1 gets the User1 result and User2 gets the User2 result is not possible in the storage trigger. The trigger can trigger whenever the file is added or modified in the blob. So, we cannot specifically get the User1/User2 result.